# how to add animations that include a scroll in the middle of the page after 2 seconds

Tags: css, angular, animation

How to add animations that start when pages are loaded. puts the scroll in the middle of the page

My code css:

```css
 

@-webkit-keyframes fadeDown {
     0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
     }
     100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(500px);
    transform: translateY(500px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(500px);
     }
   }
   @keyframes fadeDown {
     0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
     }
     100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(500px);
    transform: translateY(500px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(500px);
     }
   }
   .fadeDown {
     -webkit-animation-name: fadeDown;
     animation-name: fadeDown;
   }

  .main {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeDown;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-name: fadeDown;
    animation-duration: 2s;
  }
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <app-a>App a</app-a> 
     <div class="container">
    <app-b-menu>App b</app-b> 
     </div>  
  </div>
```

I would ask for help. I want to make animations. Sets the scroll in the middle of the page

Answer (score 0):

try this code

**html**

```
<div class="main">
          <app-a>App a</app-a> 
              <div class="container">
                <app-b-menu>App b</app-b> 
              </div>  
        </div>
```

**css**

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeDown {
              0% {
                -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
                transform: translateY(0px);
                -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
              }
              100% {
                -webkit-transform: translateY(50vh);
                transform: translateY(50vh);
                -ms-transform: translateY(50vh);
              }
            }
            @keyframes fadeDown {
              0% {
                -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
                transform: translateY(0px);
                -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
              }
              100% {
                -webkit-transform: translateY(50vh);
                transform: translateY(50vh);
                -ms-transform: translateY(50vh);
              }
            }
            .fadeDown {
              -webkit-animation-name: fadeDown;
              animation-name: fadeDown;
            }

        .main {
          -webkit-animation-name: fadeDown;
          -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
          animation-name: fadeDown;
          animation-duration: 2s;
      animation-delay: 2s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
        }
```

Comment: comes back to the beginning page

Comment: you need to stop middle of window